# How do I represent the special values for Double (Pos/Neg Infinity, NaN) in a DataView.RowFilter expression?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataview

I have a special row that contains the sum of the other rows. It always comes first in a sort but I need to be able to keep it in a RowFilter expression. The only column I have to indicate that this row is special is a column of doubles. Any of the special values for Double should work but I don't know how to test for them in the expression language. `Column = 'NaN'` did not work.

Comment: I found something that at least works. If I use PositiveInfinity as the special value, I can test Column = 'Infinity'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Double.IsNaN(Column)
```

Comment: Exception: `The expression contains undefined function call Double.IsNaN().`

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing. Does it work if you try `System.Double.IsNaN(Column)` ?

Comment: Exception: `The expression contains undefined function call System.Double.IsInfinity().`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a very small number of functions supported in the `Expression` column. Your best bet may to be to pass `null` as the `Double` value, for which you could then test with `ISNULL()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

But if you can call `System.Double.IsNaN(Column)`, that'd be much more elegant, imho.